# How do you remove underline from a link?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to remove an underline from links on a website. I tried to use "text-decoration: none;" but it wouldn't work. What syntax did I do wrong? or is there a better way to remove the underline?

```
<head>
  <style>
    font {
      color: #ff9600;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="index.html">
    <font>Home</font>
  </a>
  <a href="watch.html">     
    <font>Watch</font>
  </a>
  <a href="info.html">
    <font>Info</font>
  </a>
</body>
```

Comment: `a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }`

Comment: @PranavCBalan I already tried that. I should've clarified that above.

Comment: The `<font>` tag is [no longer officially supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), it's better to put your styling on the `<a>` tag directly

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

in your stylesheet. `text-decoration` is what adds the underline, and this code removes it.

---

**Side Note:** Also, you should not be using the `<font>` tag, as [it is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font). You should be using classes.

Comment: I just got rid of the <font> tag and also put the styling on <a> but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any other styles? Because setting the style on `a` seems to [work as expected](https://repl.it/repls/UsefulSlimCarat)

Comment: Try adding important to the end (`a { text-decoration: none !important;}`). This gives it more precedence over other styles.

Comment: @fyfles There might be a browser extension affecting this. Could you provide a link to your site?

Comment: @VFDan I forgot to mention this above, but is it important that my links are in a table?

Comment: @fyfles It actualy might be important, I'll check the repl.

Comment: @fyfles It seems like a browser extension, because it works for me.

Comment: @fyfles Try testing in another browser (with the extra code of course)

Comment: @VFDan I just tested on safari and chrome and neither worked.

Comment: @fyfles What I did is I added that rule to the top of the `<style>` tag, and it works for me.

Comment: @VFDan What rule?

Comment: @fyfles The style rule (`a { text-decoration: none !important;}`).

Comment: @fyfles Did you try adding that ^ to your style sheet?

Comment: @VFDan I did add that to my <style>

Comment: @fyfles I can't see it in the stylesheet

Comment: @fyfles No problem, but can you please accept my answer? (select the button with a checkmark)

Comment: @fyfles Also, you might want to remove the `<font>` tag because it is obsolete.

Comment: @fyfles The `<font>` can be remedied with css. Also, can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code still has an underline, is because the Anchor tag <a> by default add the underline decoration to everything inside the tag. So you will have to apply the style to the "a" instead of the font - even though the font is inside the anchor.

```
<style>
    a {
       text-decoration: none;
     }
</style>
```

Comment: It is recommended to add some supporting text that describes what you are illustrating or the point you are making.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head>
  <style>
    font {
      color: #ff9600;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="index.html">
    <font>Home</font>
  </a>
  <a href="watch.html">     
    <font>Watch</font>
  </a>
  <a href="info.html">
    <font>Info</font>
  </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

check it out hope it would work..[![

```html
<head>
<style>
     font {
          color: #ff9600;
          }
    
    a{
    
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href="index.html">
        <font>Home</font>
      </a>
      <a href="watch.html">     
        <font>Watch</font>
      </a>
      <a href="info.html">
        <font>Info</font>
      </a>
    </body>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGjsJ.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGjsJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just move `text-decoration: none;` from `font` CSS to `anchor tag a` CSS. Will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

font {
  color: #ff9600;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">
  <font>Home</font>
</a>
<a href="watch.html">     
  <font>Watch</font>
</a>
<a href="info.html">
  <font>Info</font>
</a>
```